# How to structure a component that receives a prop from redux, makes query and saves result back to redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, apollo, react-apollo

In my Redux store I am storing an accountId. This is stored by the `<Login>` component after a successful authorization. The `<Login>` component only receives the `accountId` (inside a JWT), not the full Account object with all its properties.

The `accountId` can also be modified from by other actions from other components.

When the `accountId` gets modified for whatever reason I want to fire a new GraphQL query for the full Account document, and store that in Redux too.

To this end I have created a component. I initially put the Redux dispatch pieces in `componentWillUpdate()`, but then it does not work (it does not receive the completed GraphQL query results). If I put it in `render()` like below, it works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { message } from 'antd';

// This service receives an accountId prop from Redux, and returns the complete account record
// to Redux once the graphQL query completes.

class AccountService extends React.Component {

    render() {
        if( !this.props.accountId ) {
            this.props.onAccount( null ); // Logged out -> Redux
        } else {
            if( this.props.data && this.props.data.error ) {
                console.log( this.props.data.error.message );
                message.error( this.props.data.error.message, 20 );
            }

            if( this.props.data && this.props.data.loading === false ) {
                if( this.props.data.accountById ) {
                    let account = {
                        firstName: this.props.data.accountById.firstName,
                        lastName: this.props.data.accountById.lastName,
                        // ...etc.
                    };
                    this.props.onAccount( account ); // -> Redux dispatch
                }
            }
        }

        return ( null );
    }
}

const accountQuery = gql`
query ($accountId: Int!) {accountById(id:$accountId) {
  firstName,
  lastName,
  // ...etc.
}}`;

export default graphql( accountQuery, {
    options: ( { accountId } ) => ({ variables: { accountId: accountId || 0 } }),
} )( AccountService );
```

The above component works as intended. But it throws a warning when I call the dispatch:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition
```

So apparently I m not doing things the right way. How can I structure this so that I get the results and am able to store them back into Redux without warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting the logic in componentDidUpdate if the only issue is the warning.

Comment: That actually works perfectly, and I feel kind of sheepish for not thinking of that myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `componentWillReceiveProps` for fetching account info on receiving new `accountId`.

Try this:

```
class AccountService extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      // you may need this for initial rendering
      fetchAccountInfo(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // do the GraphQL fetch only when account-ID is changed
        if (this.props.accountId !== nextProps.accountId) {
            fetchAccountInfo(nextProps); // fetch account info for new props
        }
    }

    fetchAccountInfo() {
        if( !this.props.accountId ) {
            this.props.onAccount( null ); // Logged out -> Redux
        } else {
            if( this.props.data && this.props.data.error ) {
                console.log( this.props.data.error.message );
                message.error( this.props.data.error.message, 20 );
            }

            if( this.props.data && this.props.data.loading === false ) {
                if( this.props.data.accountById ) {
                    let account = {
                      firstName: this.props.data.accountById.firstName,
                      lastName: this.props.data.accountById.lastName,
                      // ...etc.
                    };
                    this.props.onAccount(account); // -> Redux dispatch
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Never dipatch an action OR `setState` inside `render()` (you're highly vulnerable to fall into re-render loops). Probably that was causing the warning:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition
```

Comment: It looks like you have not fully understood react-apollo. The stuff you put inside fetchAccountInfo() does not do any fetching. Triggering of the query is handled automatically by react-apollo when `this.props.accountId` changes, you cannot control it that way. The interesting props to look for in `componentWillReceiveProps` is `this.props.data.loading`, but I have tried that in several ways and react-apollo does some weird stuff with `componentWillReceiveProps`. I get loading=`false` but no result object, for example.